# Django installation failed

Tags: python, django, pip

My pc recently started giving error in installing Django.... Look at the error message, what could be the cause please? [image: Django error]

I tried installing Django for my project, and it just throw an unexpected error message.
I have the right Venv activation code so I expected it to work.

Comment: Seems to me you have a connection problem.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Comment: @Solovic, please copy the text from the command prompt instead of submitting the photo so that StackOverflow could find the post later on and it would be easier to read for other users.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a weak internet connection, i.e it takes time to download, or slow internet connection. Check your internet speed and try again. If it still persists, on your virtual env try to install it manually, you can use this video as a guide [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKR0VYSOqLc).